# How can I get the visible frame of the NSScrollView's document view that is clipped?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

Let's say we have an image set to an NSScrollView's document view. When the image is smaller than the NSScrollView then there is no clipping (*the diagram on the left*).

Now say we zoom the image and it clips the scroll view (*the diagram on the right*). How can I get the region of the document view that is visible in the document view's coordinates?

[image: Diagram showing the a zoomed scroll view and coordinate frame.]

Comment: Are you looking for something other than `[NSScrollView documentVisibleRect]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `[NSScrollView documentVisibleRect]`